# background url not beneath text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a project where we are using blocks which contains text. The blocks have a header image. The result should be something like the picture below.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the image is set using the CSS background-url propertly, which makes the image go beneath the text instead of being displayed as a header image. I am using the code below, for the purpose of this question in the style of the picture above:

```
.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.header {
  background: url('https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/ZAmUp1oGGPN.png');
  background-size: contain;
  height: 300px;
}
```

This creates the `<div>` that I need, however as you can see on the picture below, it does not give me the result I want.

[image]

I have tried setting the `.header` to `display: block`, but this did not change anything. I have also tried using `margin` to force the text to be displayed under the image, which did not work either. Can someone help me to get the result I want?

The relevant HTML is down below.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="block header">
                    <h1>A Bootstrap Starter Template</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Bootstrap v3.3.6</li>
                        <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using padding? I.E. `padding-top: 300px`?

Comment: I have, it does forces the text to go under the image, but also outside of the `<div>` which is not what I want. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: So um any reason you're using `background-image` instead of an `<img>`?

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: Yes, without the HTML we can't tell what that CSS applies to.

Comment: @NoopurDabhi added the HTML which is relevant. @AvArt, I am using the `background-image` so that the image is displayed correctly, because of the `margin` inside a `block` class (see css above).

Comment: if you want your html to be below your header, then why not just move it below instead of putting it inside the header?

Comment: @KevinVoorn So, you don't want the header text appearing on top of the picture? Have you tried making another div that is not located inside of the `.header` div & entering the text there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a background image, consider using % padding. That also helps the layout stay responsive. Also, `cover` forces the background image to cover the entire div, so you don't want that at all.

```css
.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.header {
  background: url('https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/ZAmUp1oGGPN.png');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="block header">
                    <h1>A Bootstrap Starter Template</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Bootstrap v3.3.6</li>
                        <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! However I had to give my div `background-color: #fff !important` for the background color to work.

Comment: OK, though that's a different issue that doesn't involve the code you posted. An alternative is to set a more specific rule to override the competing one.

Answer (score 2):

Change your html to below:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="header">
         </div>
         <div class="block">
            <h1>A Bootstrap Starter Template</h1>
            <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
               <li>Bootstrap v3.3.6</li>
               <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You have put `block` and `header` in the same div, so your `background-color` in `.block` class is overriden by `background` of .`header` class.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xeymwbap/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me slightly although it still doesn't exactly do what I needed, the answer of ralph.m helped me a little bit more. I upvoted your answer though!

Comment: Glad that you got answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I keep my original suggestion of using an `<img>` instead of a background image. It is both easier to implement and more correct semantically.

I've tried to simulate the result in your image below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row content">
        <img class="header_img" src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/ZAmUp1oGGPN.png" />
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="block header">
            <h1>A Bootstrap Starter Template</h1>
            <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>Bootstrap v3.3.6</li>
              <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header_img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content{
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bh7Lh42k/1/